# jQuery - animate().css() complete

Tags: jquery

I have this block of code here:

`$('.section1').animate().css('overflow', 'visible');`

How do I apply a completion handler to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) `.animate` takes a callback which is triggered when animation is complete.

```
$('div').animate({ 
  top: 0 
}, 500, function (e) { 
  // Set this elements overflow to visible once
  // the animation has been completed
  $(e.currentTarget).css({overflow: 'visible'})
})
```

Comment: Do you want to set the overflow to visible once complete?

Comment: actually no, I want the element overflow to change to visible then run some code when completed.

Comment: So when do you want to set the overflow to visible? After the animation has completed? Before the animation has completed? Or is setting the overflow to visible the actual animation you want to do?

Comment: setting the overflow to visible the actual animation with a completion handler

Comment: You won't be able to animate the overflow attribute as it has no "in-between" (like width for example). So you would just use `css` attribute as you have done and the change will be instant, so no need to wait for it to complete.